# Choose delete behavior dynamically for each entry in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, relational-database

In my context I have set in initial configuration `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` for some FK relations.
But sometimes I need to remove a entry with a preconfigured Cascade behavior in its table, and I want to avoid that cascade.

Is there a simple way to achieve that?

Something like this interface?

```
public interface IBusinessContext
{

    IEnumerable<Thing> GetAllThings();

    ...

    Thing AddThing(ThingDto thingInfo);
    void RemoveThing(Thing thing, DeleteBehavior entryDeleteBehavior);
   
}
```

`DeleteBehavior` is EFCore enum type.

Comment: The delete behaviour translates to database FK constraints. So you can't really override it per request. Though I suppose with work you could emulate each option client side... somehow. eg by loading child records and setting the relationship to null explicitly.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I was thinking in set the FK value in "Restrict" and do the deletes by myself if the argument is "Cascade" or similar. Simply I was asking if there was some way I didn't see. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you could implement your own cascade / set null process. You could use the context.Model to dynamically discover the relevant foreign keys. Perhaps generating template sql scripts, so you don't have to load all the entities first.

Comment: Maybe if you know what you want to keep, unlink these items from the "parent" first, then delete and then handle your left over child items. (or leave the foreign key null for example)